# Android Studio ArticFox compiling fine but showing red errors everywhere

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose

I have a multi module Android **Compose** project. One module is an android app, others are android libraries or kotlin libraries. I'm running `AS Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Beta 5` on `MacOS 11.4 Big Sur`.

After a library upgrade (probably AGP to use compose, I don't remember when exactly) Android Studio started to show syntax errors everywhere, both in `.kts` and `.kt` files.

**Compilation and execution are working fine, only those weird JDK errors are displayed.**

Here are some examples :
[in a .kt file from a kotlin library module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWxD3.png), [in a .kts file from the buildSrc module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwPen.png)

It seems that there is an error with the JDK somewhere, but I don't understand how to fix it.

I Googled/StackOverflowed before posting here and I already tried :

- to check the JDK used Project Structure > SDK Location > Gradle. It is using the Embedded JDK 11.0.10
- to reinstall AS using Jetbrains Toolbox
- to invalidate cache and restart
- to clone my project again
- to delete ~/.gradle

But none of those actions helped...

Thanks in advance !

---

### **Update 22/07**

- I tried to create a new empty Compose project with .kts support, but no luck, everything is in red
- Because of a bug preventing to update, I updated manually to RC_1. [Here is my current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVkRb.png).
- I tried to change from Embedded JDK to a separately installed OpenJDK 11 and reimport but not luck (@alexey-belkov suggestion)
- I checked the logs but found nothing obvious (@andy suggestion)
- ℹ️ Finally I tried to create a new empty Android project with only .gradle support, and no errors ! Could it be a kotlin script plugin problem ?

Comment: I mean step one would be to not use beta software and see if you get the same issue...

Comment: I'm using Jetpack Compose that requires to be on AS Artic Fox. If you open a compose projet on AS stable version you get an error stating the compiler version does not match.

Comment: You can check the studio log which is located at `<user>/AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudio#.#/log/idea.log`.  There's likely numerous errors in the log which ultimately prevents studio from functioning properly.  A bad plugin is a typical error case.

Comment: Does the error look like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-7627? Does it help to change from Embedded JDK to a separately installed OpenJDK 11 and reimport?

Comment: @Andy sadly no obvious clue in the logs

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov It looks like the same bug indeed. Changing the JDK + removing the .idea foldr + reimporting doesn't change anything

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov As stated in my post update, I have no errors on an empty Android project with standard gradle files support